# Override routerLink on Button Click

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have an ecommerce site I'm making, and my goal is to have multiple input points per object, for instance, they click/tap anywhere on the card except the button, it will go to the product details while clicking/tapping on the button would add that item to the cart.

Currently I have no problem having it forward to the details, it will forward to the details even if the button is tapped. I'd like to have the button's action override the router.

Here's my current attempt:

```
<a *ngFor="let item of list"  >
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="card" [routerLink]="['/detail', item.item_number]">
    <img style ="width:170px;height:150px; display:block;"alt="170x150" src="{{item.item_image}}">

    <div class="card-block">
    <p class="card-text text-muted">{{item.item_name}}</p>
    <p class="card-text">Size:{{item.item_length}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">        
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="addItem()">Add<span [routerLink]="['/detail', item.item_number]" [class.disabled]="disabled ? true : null"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

I was hoping that nesting a disable command in the button would work, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas would be amazing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `stopPropagation()` to your button's click event should solve the problem:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
(click)="addItem();$event.stopPropagation()">Add<span [routerLink]="['/detail', item.item_number]" 
[class.disabled]="disabled ? true : null"></span></button>
```

This prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. Read more about `stopPropagation()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: Oi, can't believe I didn't think of $event.stopPropagation. thanks for the help. I ended up removing the span as the stopProp was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted all of my Post DIV to be linked to Post-Detail page, but I also have a slider within(think of something like Instagram which has arrows and the user can also slide it with fingers) so my solution was to put the whole div into an a tag with routerLink and put the slider in an a tag with href="javascript:void(0);" and a (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
Component Html code is like this:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/profile','feed-detail',postItem.uniqueCode]">
   <div class="content-wrap" [ngClass]="{'is-hidden': showComments}">
       ...
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <app-carousel>
                ...
            <app-carousel>
        </a><!-- closing the javascript:void(0) a tag-->
   </div> <!-- closing the content-wrap div-->
</a> <!-- closing the routerLink a tag-->
```